# Firebase - upload an static html project folder to 'Firebase Hosting' with 'Firebase Functions' and have it served?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a static website hosted on firebase hosting.

Now I have bunch of small html5 project with html/css/js file packed in folders.

Users can visit my Firebase app at "https://myfirebaseapp.com" and can upload these folders in zip format with a Cloud Functions end-point.

Hence, I need to upload these folders into Firebase Hosting's public folder via Cloud Functions so that when user hits "https://myfirebaseapp.com/[foldername]", the index.html file inside the specified folder should be served.

My plan is that I upload the zip file via Cloud Functions. Inside my function, I extract the zip file and then put all it's content to the Firebase Hosting public folder.

Is this something possible to do with Firebase?

If not, then is it something possible to do with NodeJS?

Comment: I do not think that you can use cloud functions to put assets to firebase hosting. What you are trying to achieve is similar to normal linked pages. Where one clicks this link and is redirected to a new page.

Comment: Yes. But the 'new page' is something that user will upload in form of zip. Our server shoudl extract that zip and place all the htmls and js files in the hosting folder. Is this something doable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the end. Am having trouble grasping a clear picture. Is it a site where a user uploads their own small site

Comment: What will the other users of the site be seeing

Comment: Also note what I said in the first comment.  Am not aware of such a firebase feature, anyone can correct me if I am wrong

Comment: This could require some work, but it is doable using the Hosting REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy
Take into account that you need the whole site contents each time you update it, so maybe using a repository will be a good option.